# using formulas and hyperlink in the same cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So the main idea is I want to put a Hyperlink on a cell that contains a formula, But google sheet don't like that.

I had 2 ideas.

1- Put the formula in cell `A1` and the output of that formula is dumped into cell `A2` which is gonna be Hyperlinked. 
(I tried to use `FILTER` to pull data into the Hyperlinked cell but it would give me a `#REF!` error:`Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in A2.`)

2- Use some sort of `apps-script` of which I have very little understanding of, so I didn't find any scripts relating to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand the reason why you can't put a Hyperlink AND a formula in the same cell, But as far as I understood: 
Hyperlink is a formula it self → `=HYPERLINK(url, [link_label])`

So instead of Hyperlinking our cell using the UI, we can use the formula form to Hyperlink the cell and use our formula in the place of `[link_label]` which is gonna be the name of our cell: 
`=HYPERLINK(     url    , [link_label])` 
`=HYPERLINK("google.com",  SUM(B2:B5 ))`